# Virtualbox - windows - no internet access when using bridge

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox

I have installed a `windows xp` on my virtual machine.
I have set the network to use bridge.

On the virtual machine I can ping `www.google.com`, I can telnet `www.google.com`. But I cannot connect via `IExplorer`, for some reason only `msn.com` is connecting.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this on a Windows XP VM in Virtualbox so it should work for you.

Do the following in Internet Explorer

1. Go to **Tools**
2. Select **Internet Options**
3. Go to the **Advanced** tab
4. Scroll down to the bottom under **Security**
5. Enable the **Use TLS 1.0** checkbox
6. Click **Apply** and now refresh Internet Explorer

[image]